# Universal TFieldGetTextEvent

Tags: delphi

I have a problem with using interface for Event.
I have this sample:

```
procedure TForm1.DateOnGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: string;
DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
...some code
end;
```

Now I using on this form:

```
DS.DataSet.FieldByName('Uhrada').OnGetText:=DateOnGetText;
```

This is OK,but I need decouple this with interface:

```
IFieldDisplayFormatter=interface(IInvokable)
['{C21CA5D7-0BDA-4C5D-A495-F7C34B0D3E3A}']
  procedure OnGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
end;
```

implementation for example:

```
type
  TCacheDateFieldFormater=class(TInterfacedObject,IFieldDisplayFormatter)
  public
    procedure OnGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
  end;
```

Now I can using this aka:

```
var
  FieldFormater:IFieldDisplayFormatter;

  DS.DataSet.FieldByName('Uhrada').OnGetText:=FieldFormater.OnGetText;
```

But compiler say error where this is not compatible.
Why?
How can I realise this,please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interface method as event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422142/interface-method-as-event-handler)

Answer (score 1):

Change the interface declaration to:

```
IFieldDisplayFormatter=interface(IInvokable)
['{C21CA5D7-0BDA-4C5D-A495-F7C34B0D3E3A}']
  function GetOnGetText: TFieldGetTextEvent;
  property OnGetText: TFieldGetTextEvent read GetOnGetText;
end;
```

And change implementation to:

```
type
  TCacheDateFieldFormater=class(TInterfacedObject,IFieldDisplayFormatter)
  private
    procedure InternalOnGetText(Sender: TField; var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
  public
    function GetOnGetText: TFieldGetTextEvent;
  end;

TCacheDateFieldFormater.GetOnGetText;
begin
  Result := InternalOnGetText;
end;
```